# How do i turn a normal function to a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a problem turninf1g this code into a recursive function . My main problem is trying to figure out how to check if its greater than f1 in the recursion . Th code works perfectly on its own but i wish to turn it to a recursive function if possible.

```
def countTerms(n):
    f1=1+1+1/math.factorial(n)
    m=1
    f2=pow((1+1/m),m)
    while f2<f1:
        m+=1
        f2=pow((1+1/m),m)
    return round(f2,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a recursive function has an `if` with two cases: the base case (when the computation is done) and the recursive case (when you still need to break down the problem set a little further). In this instance, the base case is when `f2` reaches or exceeds `f1`:

```
import math

def countTerms(n, m=1, f2=2):
    f1 = 2 + 1 / math.factorial(n)
    if f2 < f1:
        return countTerms(n, m=m + 1, f2=(1 + 1 / m) ** m)
    else:
        return math.round(f2, 2)
```

EDIT: Added explicit keyword args to the recursive call to make it more clear how `m` and `f2` are updated for each successive iteration.

Comment: Also, just a note, `n` stays fixed throughout the computation, and `f1` is defined purely in terms of `n`, so it stays fixed too. Therefore, you could precompute `f1` and make that the first parameter, rather than `n`, and cut down on the repeated calls to `math.factorial`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to this:

```
def count_terms(n, m=1):
    f1 = 1 + 1 + 1 / math.factorial(n)
    f2 = pow((1 + 1 / m), m)
    if f2 >= f1:
        return round(f2, 2)
    else:
        m += 1
        count_terms(n, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something called tail recursion [What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).

I assume this is a HW problem? What you want to determine are the base case, termination condition and update rule -- can you reformulate your `while` loop in those terms?